# Bash shows my private key id_rsa to be present, even when it is not there (Opp also true). How so?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh, terminal

Connected successfully (over ssh) from Bash on Win10 PC to DigitalOcean ubuntu droplet.
I was assuming that I've my private key present at ~/.ssh/id_rsa (in Win10 bash system this path translates to `C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\bobu\.ssh`.

Even when I list the contents of above folder thru LS command in Bash, it shows the private key present. Even when I create a file or folder is at this very location, that file or folder is also shown while listing/viewing the contents.

But problem is that windows explorer has stopped showing the private key file, or even other `config` file or even a copy of `id_rsa.pub` file at that very location. 
And I'm 100% sure that I'm looking at the correct folder location in Win10 explorer, because if I create a file or folder thru bash terminal at that location, the same is immediately shown in the win10 explorer.

So, in short, my question is, how can I find my private key file and other config files in Windows explorer? How can I delete the same from windows if I wanted?

Comment: The contrary is also true. I.e. if I delete all files from bash at the specified location (~/.ssh) and in windows explorer I add private key files at that very location, then bash doesn't show those key files present. But if I add some other folder etc, that is shown/synced across.

Comment: Is it possible that files added (or any other changes made) in the bash locations thru Windows explorer can't be seen by actual bash terminal?